# H13 (Connection closed without response) errors on Heroku scale down

Tags: django, nginx, heroku, uwsgi, supervisord

I am running Django app in Docker image with uWSGI, supervisor and nginx on Heroku.

I am often getting H13 (Connection closed without response) errors when the app is scaling down:

[image]

This problem generates following log events:

```
2022-10-12T09:35:13.231318+00:00 heroku web.3 - - State changed from up to down
2022-10-12T09:35:13.774228+00:00 heroku web.3 - - Stopping all processes with SIGTERM
2022-10-12T09:35:14.028602+00:00 heroku router - - at=error code=H13 desc="Connection closed without response" method=GET path="/comments/api/assets-uuidasset/xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxx/count/?_=1665564563"
```

I expect the problem lies in either the socket not closing on SIGTERM signal or nginx closing ungracefully with SIGTERM signal (it should receive SIGQUIT for graceful shutdown) or something similar.

The first case is described in this article regarding Puma and Ruby: https://www.schneems.com/2019/07/12/puma-4-hammering-out-h13sa-debugging-story/

The second case is described here: https://canonical.com/blog/avoiding-dropped-connections-in-nginx-containers-with-stopsignal-sigquit

Answer (score 1):

After three weeks of work I had been finally able to fix this issue.

## Short answer:

**Avoid using Heroku to run Docker images if you can.**

Heroku sends `SIGTERM` to ALL processes in the dyno, which is something that is very hard to deal with. You will need patch almost every process inside the Docker container to count with `SIGTERM` and terminate nicely.

Standard way of terminating Docker container is with `docker stop` command which sends `SIGTERM` ONLY to root process (entrypoint), where it can be dealt with.

Heroku has very arbitrary process of terminating the instance incompatible with existing applications as well as existing Docker image deployments. And according to my communication with Heroku they are unable to change this in the future.

## Long answer:

There was not one single issue but 5 separate issues.
In order to terminate the instance successfully following conditions needs to be fulfilled:

- Nginx has to be terminate first and start last (so the Heroku router stops sending requests, this is similar to [Puma](https://www.schneems.com/2019/07/12/puma-4-hammering-out-h13sa-debugging-story/)) and it has to be graceful, which is usually done with SIGQUIT signal.
- Other applications needs to terminate gracefully in correct order - in my case first Nginx, than Gunicorn and PGBouncer as the last. The order of terminating the applications is important - e.g. PGBouncer must terminate after Gunicorn to not interrupt running SQL queries.
- The `docker-entrypoint.sh` needs to catch the `SIGTERM` signal. This didn't show up when I was testing locally.

In order to achieve this I had to deal with every application separately:

### Nginx:

I had to patch Nginx to swich `SIGTERM` and `SIGQUIT` signals, so I run following command in my Dockerfile:

```
# Compile nginx and patch it to switch SIGTERM and SIGQUIT signals
RUN curl -L http://nginx.org/download/nginx-1.22.0.tar.gz -o nginx.tar.gz \
  && tar -xvzf nginx.tar.gz \
  && cd nginx-1.22.0 \
  && sed -i "s/ QUIT$/TIUQ/g" src/core/ngx_config.h \
  && sed -i "s/ TERM$/QUIT/g" src/core/ngx_config.h \
  && sed -i "s/ TIUQ$/TERM/g" src/core/ngx_config.h \
  && ./configure --without-http_rewrite_module \
  && make \
  && make install \
  && cd .. \
  && rm nginx-1.22.0 -rf \
  && rm nginx.tar.gz
```

[Issue I created](https://trac.nginx.org/nginx/ticket/2401)

### uWSGI/Gunicorn:

I gave up on uWSGI and swiched to Gunicorn (which terminates gracefully on `SIGTERM`), but I had to patch it anyways in the end, because it needs to terminate later than Nginx. I disabled `SIGTERM` signal and mapped it's function on `SIGUSR1`
My patched version is here: https://github.com/PetrDlouhy/gunicorn/commit/1414112358f445ce714c5d4f572d78172b993b79

I install it with:

```
RUN poetry run pip install -e git+https://github.com/PetrDlouhy/gunicorn@no_sigterm#egg=gunicorn[gthread] \
   && cd `poetry env info -p`/src/gunicorn/ \
   && git config core.repositoryformatversion 0  # Needed for Dockerfile.test only untill next version of Dulwich is released \
   && cd /project
```

[Issue I created](https://github.com/benoitc/gunicorn/issues/2884)

### PGBouncer:

I also deployed PGBouncer which I had to modify to not react on `SIGTERM` with:

```
# Compile pgbouncer and patch it to switch SIGTERM and SIGQUIT signals
RUN curl -L https://github.com/pgbouncer/pgbouncer/releases/download/pgbouncer_1_17_0/pgbouncer-1.17.0.tar.gz -o pgbouncer.tar.gz \
  && tar -xvzf pgbouncer.tar.gz \
  && cd pgbouncer-1.17.0 \
  && sed -i "s/got SIGTERM, fast exit/PGBouncer got SIGTERM, do nothing/" src/main.c \
  && sed -i "s/ exit(1);$//g" src/main.c \
  && ./configure \
  && make \
  && make install \
  && cd .. \
  && rm pgbouncer-1.17.0 -rf \
  && rm pgbouncer.tar.gz
```

It still can be brought down gracefully with `SIGINT`.

[Issue I created](https://github.com/pgbouncer/pgbouncer/issues/770)

### docker-entrypoint.sh

I had to trap `SIGTERM` in my `docker-entrypoint.sh` with:

```bash
_term() {
  echo "Caught SIGTERM signal. Do nothing here, because Heroku already sent signal everywhere."
}

trap _term SIGTERM
```

### supervisor

In order to not receive `R12` errors all processes needs to terminate before 30 second Heroku graceful period. I achieved it by setting priorities in `supervisord.conf`:

```
[supervisord]
nodaemon=true

[program:gunicorn]
command=poetry run newrelic-admin run-program gunicorn wsgi:application -c /etc/gunicorn/gunicorn.conf.py
priority=2
stopsignal=USR1
...

[program:nginx]
command=/usr/local/nginx/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
priority=3
...

[program:pgbouncer]
command=/usr/local/bin/pgbouncer /project/pgbouncer/pgbouncer.ini
priority=1
stopsignal=INT
...
```

## Testing the solutions:

In order to test what was going on, I had to develop some testing techniques which might come handy in different but similar cases.

I created a view which waits 10 seconds before answer and bind it on `/slow_view` url.

Then I started the server in Docker instance, made query to the slow view with `curl -I "http://localhost:8080/slow_view"` and made second connection to the Docker instance and executed kill command with `pkill -SIGTERM .` or e.g. `pkill -SIGTERM gunicorn`.

I could also run the kill command on testing Heroku dyno where I connected with `heroku ps:exec --dyno web.1 --app my_app`.